# How to set eclipse console locale/language

Tags: java, eclipse

When developing web application with Eclipse (Helios) the tomcat output is being sent to the console. Ok, but the messages are being translated to my OS language.

In fact, my Eclipse is in English, but the Tomcat output (logging) is being translated to Portuguese. Probably it's a Tomcat configuration issue, but I can't find where...

How do I change this behaviour? I want my entire Eclipse in English, including Tomcat.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Go to *Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > select preferred JRE > Edit* and then add the following to *Default VM arguments*:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
```

[image]

Comment: That will make the change for all java apps. Not a solution for everybody. Adding it to the eclipse.ini might be the better option.

Answer (score 10):

Try adding `-Duser.language=en` in the bottom of your *eclipse.ini* which is found in your eclipse installation directory (keep a backup copy of the eclipse.ini before any changes).

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried setting the following -D parameters in the launch configuration?

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.variant=EN
```

Answer (score 1):

> As @Rich and other answers said above::

You can add `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US` to the `Run Configuration > VM arg` for a specific java file.

[image: Add to the Run Configuration]