# Adding and subtracting doubles are giving strange results

Tags: java, double

So when I add or subtract in Java with Doubles, it giving me strange results. Here are some:

If I add `0.0 + 5.1`, it gives me `5.1`. That's correct.

If I add `5.1 + 0.1`, it gives me `5.199999999999` (The number of repeating `9`s may be off). That's wrong.

If I subtract `4.8 - 0.4`, it gives me `4.39999999999995` (Again, the repeating `9`s may be off). That's wrong.

At first I thought this was only the problem with adding doubles with decimal values, but I was wrong. The following worked fine:

```
5.1 + 0.2 = 5.3
5.1 - 0.3 = 4.8
```

Now, the first number added is a double saved as a variable, though the second variable grabs the text from a `JTextField`. For example:

```
//doubleNum = 5.1 RIGHT HERE
//The textfield has only a "0.1" in it.
doubleNum += Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
//doubleNum = 5.199999999999999
```

Comment: btw, prefer using BigDecimal (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html )

Comment: Actually, 5.19999999... (with infinitely many repeating 9's) is mathematically exactly the same as 5.2, if you don't believe it, try to find out what the difference between the two is. It is 0, hence, they are the same.

Comment: @Ingo technically, yes, but I would like to have a little bit precise answer :)

Comment: Rob, I understand, and I find it very regrettable that those numbers are known as "float" and "double". Appropriate names would be "coarse approximations" and "slightly better, but still coarse approximations"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Java, `double` values are [IEEE floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).  Unless they are a power of 2 (or sums of powers of 2, e.g. 1/8 + 1/4 = 3/8), they cannot be represented exactly, even if they have high precision.  Some floating point operations will compound the round-off error present in these floating point numbers.  In cases you've described above, the floating-point errors have become significant enough to show up in the output.

It doesn't matter what the source of the number is, whether it's parsing a string from a `JTextField` or specifying a `double` literal -- the problem is inherit in floating-point representation.

Workarounds:

- If you know you'll only have so many decimal points, then use integer
  arithmetic, then convert to a decimal:

  ```
  (double) (51 + 1) / 10
  (double) (48 - 4) / 10
  ```
- Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)
- If you must use `double`, you can cut down on floating-point errors
  with the [Kahan Summation Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Comment: Do you think if I used `float`s instead that it will give a more accurate value?

Comment: A `float` generally only has half the precision of a `double`.  That's not a good idea if you need the precision.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, doubles use IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) Wikipedia article), which is inherently inaccurate. Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for perfect decimal precision. To round in printing, accepting merely "pretty good" accuracy, use `printf("%.3f", x)`.