# Incorrect subtraction results: 3.999999, not 4

Tags: java, int, double, rounding

So I narrowed down a bug in my application to java messing up a simple subtraction calculation. I can't figure out why exactly. Here is the bit of code:

```
    for (double x = (((double)bdl.length())-1)/10; x > 0; x--) {
            int count;
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            if (x >= 1) {
                System.out.println("X = " + x + " so count = 20");
                count = (20);
            } else {
                count = (int)(x*20);
                System.out.println("X = " + x + " so count = "+count);
            }
    }
```

The variable bdl is just a JSONArray, which I am only concerned with its length at this point. As bdl comes in initially it has length 15, so x will equal 1.4 . The first time through the loop the first println says "X = 1.4 so count = 20" which is correct. The second time through however when x should = 0.4, it instead says "X = 0.3999999999999999 so count = 7". I understand that casting (x*20) to an int at that point and time will give me 7, but my question is Why is x not equal to 0.4 .

Comment: ObReference: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You should know what is the correct type to use before blaming Java.

Comment: This is due to floating point arithmetic.  You can try to round the answer to a certain number of decimal spots if it bothers you or just truncate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625556/java-adding-and-subtracting-doubles-are-giving-strange-results

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `double`, which is a floating-point number. This is not meant for presision, moreover, it is meant for speed and non-precision. So instead, you should be using an `int`, like this:

```
for (int x = ((bdl.length())-1)/10; x > 0; x--) {
```

This will keep your numbers precise.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your 'x' does equal 0.4, it's only a matter of precision.

All floating point comparison operations should be executed with a certain precision (delta or epsilon in some implementations).

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java).