# Java - Numbers aren't subtracting correctly?

Tags: java, math

So I've been starting to make a Cash Register program which will take in what the user is paying and how much the object costs.  This will tell the user how much coins (Toonies, loonies, etc.) they'll get in return.  **Here's the part of the code that determines how much coins the user will get in return:**

```
if(amountPayed >= amountToPay) {
    remainder = amountPayed - amountToPay;

    while(remainder > 0) {

        if(remainder >= 2) {
            toonies++;
            remainder = remainder - 2;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }

        else if(remainder >= 1) {
            loonies++;
            remainder = remainder - 1;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }

        else if(remainder >= 0.25) {
            quarters++;
            remainder = remainder - 0.25;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }

        else if(remainder >= 0.1) {
            dimes++;
            remainder = remainder - 0.1;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }

        else if(remainder >= 0.05) {
            nickels++;
            remainder = remainder - 0.05;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }

        else if(remainder >= 0.01) {
            pennies++;
            remainder = remainder - 0.01;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }

    }
```

I've been having a problem with getting the correct amount, the loop ended up being infinite.  I thought to myself, this can't be true as I made sure that all the values would go through evenly.

I decided I should do some debugging so I made it output the remainder everytime it went through.  Here's what I got:

```
18.01
16.01
14.010000000000002
12.010000000000002
10.010000000000002
8.010000000000002
6.010000000000002
4.010000000000002
2.0100000000000016
0.010000000000001563
1.5629858518551032E-15
```

This was very weird to me because the numbers I entered only went to the second decimal.  I was subtracting the numbers from the remainder just fine.  So what's my problem?

Comment: What is the type of all the associated variables?

Comment: It appears you are using `double` for your money amounts. `BigDecimal` with scale 2 would work much better. `double` is a form of base 2 scientific notation in which your numbers cannot be represented exactly, only to a very close approximation - fine for engineering, not so good for money.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh They are doubles.

Comment: Consider using longs to represent values in pence (or equivalent unit) to avoid rounding issues

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Could you explain why doubles weren't working very well in this situation?

Comment: This is the problem with double precision -- check it here --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625556/java-adding-and-subtracting-doubles-are-giving-strange-results. Use `BigDecimal` to remove these issues

Comment: Because base-2.  You can't represent 1/3 without recursion in decimal; binary numbers can't represent certain values because they have no ability to deal with numeric recursion; they truncate.

Comment: @ZacharyVincze For example, the closest double to 18.01 is 18.010000000000001563194018672220408916473388671875

Comment: Take a read here for more info: http://floating-point-gui.de