# Dart - Subtracting some double values gives wrong result

Tags: dart, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy

I have picked two random `double` numbers:

```
double a = 7918.52;
double b = 5000.00;
```

I would expect to get `2918.52` from `a - b`.
Well, it gives me a result of `2918.5200000000004`, which seems odd.

```
print(a - b); // -> 2918.5200000000004
```

But if I change `double a` to `7918.54`, I will get the expected result of `2918.54`.

Can someone explain to me why some `double` values result in unexpected rounding issues and others do not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) and the fact that Dart uses the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) as far as I am concerned.

This happens for all languages that use floating-point arithmetic. You can read through [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15625556/6509751) regarding other programming languages.

[General question about floating-point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6509751) in modern programming languages.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it.

Answer (score 1):

creativecreatorormaybenot is right, this is issue comes from the Dart language itself.

The best solution I came up with was to manually round it to the precision you expect :

```
double substract(double a, double b, int precision) {
  return (a - b).precision(precision);
}

double precision(int fractionDigits) {
  num mod = pow(10.0, fractionDigits);
  return ((this * mod).round().toDouble() / mod);
}
```

If you do this, you will have the result you showed only if you ask a precision that is superior to ~12, but I doubt that it will ever ever be your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

- depending on how many decimals you expect (lets assume 2, you can make it more generic...)
- `((a * 100).toInt() - (b * 100)).toInt() / 100`.