# Working with cents and thousands in java

Tags: java

I have an input which can have a 13 long decimal number with cents and thousands separators. So i can have something like this:

```
13.213.232.132,13
```

The same field on my database table is configured to be a NUMBER(13,2) column (oracle)

How can i convert from

```
13.213.232.132,13 to 13213232132,13
```

and Vice-Versa?

Comment: Convert to a string, remove the periods, then convert back, no?

Comment: Isn't the input already a string, considering it contains coma **and** periods ?

Comment: What form does it come back to you in when you read it from the database? Is it a `String`?

Comment: Do you have NLS_LANG set on the database? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: How are you viewing the value now? Are you reading it as a `double` from the database, and printing it out in your current locale?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use NumberFormat.parse() -- get an instance of NumberFormat to match your locale, create a string indicating the format expected, then parse the input with it.

Answer (score 2):

## SOLUTION 1

You might want to use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Here's an example on how to use it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
class NumberConverter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double number = 12312312312.31;
        String pattern = "###.##";
        String pattern2 = "###,###.##";
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
        System.out.println(myFormatter.format(number));
        myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern2);
        System.out.println(myFormatter.format(number));
    }
}
```

All you need to do with this example is replace `,` for `.` and viceversa. (I mean separators).

The actual output for my example is:

```
12312312312.31
12,312,312,312.31
```

---

## SOLUTION 2

Here's another option on how to achieve it, code taken from @JonSkeet [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236096/2180785). Setting locale, but again assuming your number is a double.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
class NumberConverter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double number = 13213232132.13;
        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
        ((DecimalFormat) f).applyPattern("##0,000.00");
        System.out.println(f.format(number));
    }
}
```

---

## SOLUTION 3

If your input is a `String` then this could be another way of solving (Since it's a 13 length number that's why I use those limits).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
class NumberConverter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String number = "13.213.232.132,13";
        String number1;
        String number2;
        
        number1 = number.replace(".", "");
        
        int length;
        int length1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        sb.append(number1.charAt(0));
        sb.append(number1.charAt(1));
        sb.append(".");
        
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
            if(counter == 3) {
                sb.append(".");
                counter = 0;
            }
            sb.append(number1.charAt(i));
            counter++;
        }
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(number1.charAt(12));
        sb.append(number1.charAt(13));
        
        number2 = sb.toString();
        
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(number1);
        System.out.println(number2);
    }
}
```

---

## SOLUTION 4

As @kaos said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190047/working-with-cents-and-thousands-in-java#comment39227547_25190284) you can also do it by using `DecimalFomatSymbols` in this way:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
class NumberConverter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String formatString = "###,###.##";
        double number = 12312312312.31;
        DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
        
        System.out.println(df.format(number));
    }
}
```

Any of these examples might help you in what you're trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to parse the number that has `.` as a thousands separator and `,` as a decimal point. It presumes the number is already in a `double`, which seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: @DavidConrad yeah might not be the exact solution, I'm looking for a "custom" decimal format which allows to do that. OP didn't specify if it was a double or a string. Working on another solution.

Comment: If it was a double, it couldn't have thousands separators in it.

Comment: Maybe it was an example on how it looks like right now (with a decimal format not specified by OP either)

Comment: You can use DecimalFomatSymbols for changing thousand and decimal characters.

Comment: @kaos do you have an example? so I can update it with it, and add it with my last solution (when input isn't a double).

Comment: @Frakcool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054132/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-of-decimalformat-from-comma-to-dot-point

Comment: @kaos check update, not sure if it's what you said :)

Comment: @DavidConrad could you check updates? There's an update when it's not a `double` but a `String` instead.

Comment: Comprehensive! I notice you have "solvind" for "solving" at one place, BTW.

Comment: @Frakcool Yeap that's it. You can eventually change Locale.GERMAN to Locale.getDefault() as it will return the current Locale for JVM instead of switching it to Germany.

Comment: @kaos oh thanks I also learned from this answer some things C: updated btw

Answer (score 1):

Use DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "br"));
    formatter.applyPattern("#0.##"); //i guess this is the pattern you need.

    System.out.println(formatter.format(new BigDecimal("13213232132.13")));
```

Answer (score 0):

A very ugly approach, maybe it helps:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String str = "12.345.678.912,13";
    final String improved = str.replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll(",", ".");
    System.out.println(improved);
    final double dbl = Double.parseDouble(improved);
    System.out.println("For database: " + dbl);
    // You may even pass a Locale to String::format
    final String str2 = String.format("%,f", dbl);
    System.out.println(str2);

    final String stringResult = str2.substring(0, str2.length() - 4);
    System.out.println(stringResult);
}
```