# Change comma to period in double android

Tags: android, double

I want to have my double displayed like this `12.34` but at the moment its displaying like this `12,34`. I want to have a period instead of a comma. Can anyone help?

```
Double tmp = CalculatePercentage(model.getTotal(),model.getAchieved(),Double.parseDouble(model.getWeight()),"W");
holder.textView_contribution.setText("End Weight: "+String.format("%.2f", tmp));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating your own instance of `DecimalFormat` and configuring it (a) to use your custom decimal separator and (b) use your desired number of fractional digits:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');

DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

You can then use this to set the value of your TextView

```
holder.textView_contribution.setText("End Weight: " + format.format(tmp));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to the locale of the device. The decimal separator can either be a period or a comma.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

EDIT: possibly relevant
[Force point (".") as decimal separator in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236056/force-point-as-decimal-separator-in-java)