# How to set language for R-console (StatET) in Eclipse on MacOS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, r, statet

I'd like to set the language for my R-console outputs in Eclipse (StatET)
from the OS language to english. I am working on Mac OS X.
I tried the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947484/how-to-set-eclipse-console-locale-language) by setting the language in the JRE-preferences, but that didn't work. See screenshot.
[image: Language setting for JRE-Eclipse]

Where resp. How do I need to set things?
Has anyone experience with such a setup?

/j

Comment: There's a /etc/Rconsole file in your R installation directory where language can be specified. If you switch that to language=en, does that work for you?

Comment: I don't know where I should find this file on my Mac OSX. I couldn't find this in the R/contents/...

Answer (score 0):

'you can override the auto-detection performed by setting `force.LANG' defaults setting, such as for example

```
 defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

when run in Terminal it will enforce US-english setting regardless of the system setting. Please note that you must always use `.UTF-8' version of the locale, otherwise R.app will not work properly.'

From [Internationalization of the R.app](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Internationalization-of-the-R_002eapp) in the R for Mac OS X FAQ.

Let me know if this works for you.

Best,
Eric

Comment: Hi, I tried that line in the terminal. It changes the language for my R.app (thats now english), but nothing changed for the Eclipse console, that still in my OS-language?!?

Comment: I see, well I believe you have to change the `Info.plist`, there are some instructions one third down [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Speak-The-Local-Language/article.html).

Comment: Hi, just to be clear again, I don't want to change the language of Eclipse itself (it is already in english). I'd rather like to change the language of the R-console output (probably a setting with statet).  So R.app-console and Eclipse are in english, R-statet-console in Eclipse not.