# Bloomberg emulator giving NumberFormatException

Tags: java, bloomberg

I am trying to use the Bloomberg API emulator instead of the actual Bloomberg API because as far as I understood you need to have a Bloomberg Terminal in order to use it and the emulator will be good enough for my project as I do not need real data to test it. So I have created a new project and imported the Jar file of the bbg emulator and I am able to run it but I get a runtime numberformatexception. Normally I would debug and fix the exception but since I am using the Jar file I do not know how to fix it. Does anyone have any experience with the bbg emulator with java? All I need is to send and receive basic data. If anyone can give some advice or any links It would be appreciated. I have the bbg api documentation

[image]

Comment: You can open the jar file using winzip/winrar or any similar software. And then using a decompiler you can decompile the class which you see in stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is wrong in English. It should be 0.722 with a dot, and not a comma. If you change it to use the English notation (dots and not commans in decimal numbers) you wont get that error.

Comment: I've had similar problem, how do you change it to the English notation in Eclipse

Comment: I have found how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947484/how-to-set-eclipse-console-locale-language