# How to set the language of svn plugin's in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

[image]

After a installation, my subversion plugin init show in Chinese language, How to set it to English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Which of the two plugins are you using? There's Eclipse's Subversive plugin and CollabNet's Subclipse.
- How did you install these plugins? Did you use the standard URL and had Eclipse automatically install the right plugins, or did you manually load them and specify a zip file to load?

All plugins should take your computer's default language setting or the language you specified via the `-nl` parameter in the `eclipse.ini` file.

You might want to try uninstalling and reinstalling the plugins again, but do it through the URL.

Comment: I look the detail of the plugin, it shows that this is called " CollabNet's Subclipse"

Comment: How did you install it? Did you go through the URL installation or did you download the plugin and install the zip file?

Comment: Follow your notice about eclipse.ini file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947484/how-to-set-eclipse-console-locale-language  I use the -D option, it works! thank you David

Answer (score 0):

Just go to help > about Eclipse > Installation Details > Subversive Localization. and click Uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-Duser.language=en` into `eclipse.ini`.