# How can I force Eclipse to show English on console?

Tags: java

I tried to use date variable and show on console using format but it shows Thai. How can I force it to show English?

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("E M y 'at' hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(ft.format(dNow));
```

The result is

```
พ. 12 2558 at 09:06:32
```

ps. expected result

```
Thursday 12 2015 at 09:06:32
```

I have tried this way but it doesn't work.
[How to set eclipse console locale/language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947484/how-to-set-eclipse-console-locale-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your eclipse to be in english language completely:

- Go to the directory where you "installed" eclipse
- Open the file "eclipse.ini" (preferrably with some editor that shows the linebreaks)
- Insert the line "-Duser.language=en_US" at the end of the file

and voila your eclipse should be in english language and all 
Locales will be in english!

---

If you don't want to change the language of your eclipse or this doesn't work for some reason you can always apply the Locale you're working in manually:

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("E M y 'at' hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(ft.format(dNow));
```