# Read alternating data types from file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read coordinates from a file into an array.

Every coordinate has an id, an `x-value` and a `y-value`.

The file is in the following format: `id position.x position.y`

**Example:**

```
292961234 1376.42 618.056
29535583 3525.73 530.522
256351971 836.003 3563.33
20992560 4179.74 3074.27
```

Note: There are 4 lines containing a total of 4 coordinates.

I created the class `Node` and its constructor expects `(int id, double x, double y)`.

And this is the class NodeList which is supposed to have an array attribute that saves the Nodes:

```java
package .....;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NodeList implements Iterable<Node> {
    private Node[] nodes = getNodes();
    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
    public Node[] getNodes() {
        Node[] result;
        File f;
        Scanner scanner;
        try {
            f = new File("nodes.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
            int ctr = 0;
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                ctr++;
                s.nextLine();
            }
            result = new Node[ctr];
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(f);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("C"));
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            int id = scanner.nextInt();
            double x = scanner.nextDouble();
            double y = scanner.nextDouble();
            result[i] = new Node(id,x,y);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeList nl = new NodeList();
    }
}
```

The `Node` class:

```java
package ...;

public class Node {
    private int id;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    public Node(int id, double x, double y){
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

When the method containing the shown code is called, I get the following 
**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at ......NodeList.getNodes(NodeList.java:40)
    at ......NodeList.<init>(NodeList.java:9)
    at ......NodeList.main(NodeList.java:47)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Link to the file containing the nodes: https://pastebin.com/zhzp3DTi

Comment: What is `scanner`? Are you trying to use `Scanner` object to read a file? Also, try using a comma instead of a dot on your double expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to read a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/java-how-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912470/why-is-nextdouble-from-the-scanner-method-sending-me-exception

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's a related answer for reading just integers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788114/509840. Do you think you could modify your code to read an integer and a double?

Comment: @GauravMall scanner is a Scanner object that reads from my file. Our teachers gave us a file where they used dots so I guess I have to stick with that.

Comment: I got that. The error that you are up against is actually that of a locale

Comment: Check out the duplicate links provided by the users.

Comment: Can you post the node class too? Because it is showing that the error is caused by `NodeList.getNodes()`

Comment: It looks like your input file is corrupted can you post the exact content of your input file?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom It's more than 8000 lines, are you sure?

Comment: Can you post a link to the file?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom I added the link at the end of my question.

Comment: I tested it with the file it seems to work perfectly. I think you need to post your entire class, because we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @StephanHogenboom I added the full class to my question.

Comment: @Jumpman i ran your full code example with the pastebin data and it works just fine. Im afraid something is wrong with the localdata you are processing. The error message sais you arw parsing a field that is either not an int or double as a double or int

Comment: @StephanHogenboom What is the localdata?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that it is using wrong locale.
I don't think "C" is a valid locale, it should be a language code.

You can try to use

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.ROOT);
```

This is working on my machine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String s = "292961234 1376.42 618.056\n" +
               "29535583 3525.73 530.522\n" +
               "256351971 836.003 3563.33\n" +
               "20992560 4179.74 3074.27";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    scanner.useLocale(Locale.ROOT);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int id = scanner.nextInt();
        double x = scanner.nextDouble();
        double y = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(id+" "+x+" "+y);
    }
}
```

Comment: For this exercise we already had a little bit of code given and it included this line in order to read dots as decimals for the doubles.

Comment: It also works on my machine, i think the problem is in the file he is processing

Comment: Your example also works with `Locale("C")` and when not specifying any `Locale`