# toString() method of org.joda.time.DateTime failed when Danish is set as VM argument

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, datetime-format

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Interval;

public class JordaTimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = dateFormat1;

        Interval interval = new Interval(1499628963860L, 1511809983860L);
        DateTime start = new DateTime(interval.getStart());
        DateTime end = new DateTime(interval.getEnd());

        System.out.println(start.toString(dateFormat.toLocalizedPattern()));
    }
}
```

I followed the way specified in [How to set eclipse console locale/language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947484/how-to-set-eclipse-console-locale-language)

I used `-Duser.language=da -Duser.country=DK` as VM arguments. I'm getting exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: tt

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: You're trying to format a joda DateTime with the localized pattern of a SimpleDateFormat, used to format and parse java.util.Date instances. Use a joda DateTimeFormat pattern, as documented: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString(java.lang.String). What you're doing is basically equivalent to trying to identify a French citizen using an American social security number.

Comment: It's actually worse than that: it's like trying to identify a French citizen using an American social security number written in Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the locale to **da_DK**, the method `toLocalizedPattern` returns `EEE tt/MM HH:mm`, and `tt` [is not a recognized pattern](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) in Joda-Time.

If you want the output in a specific language, you don't need to change the JVM default locale (because this can affect all other applications running in the same JVM). Instead, you can create a `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and set the locale only in the formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat
    // set pattern
    .forPattern("EEE dd/MM HH:mm")
    // set locale
    .withLocale(new Locale("da", "DK"));
System.out.println(fmt.print(start));
System.out.println(fmt.print(end));
```

This will output:

> sø 09/07 16:36
>   ma 27/11 17:13

Please note that the output depends on the JVM default timezone: `1499628963860` corresponds to UTC `2017-07-09T19:36:03.860Z`, which is 16:36 in my JVM's default timezone (`America/Sao_Paulo`). In your machine, the values will be different.

If you want to specify a timezone, you could create your dates like:

```
// create date in UTC
DateTime start = new DateTime(interval.getStart(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Now the `DateTime` is in UTC, so the output will be `sø 09/07 19:36`.

You can also set to a specific timezone using `DateTimeZone.forID("zonename")`, where `zonename` is a valid [IANA timezone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `DateTimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

---

As explained in [@JB Nizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302652/tostring-method-of-org-joda-time-datetime-failed-when-danish-is-set-as-vm-argu/46303333#comment79567942_46302652), there's no need to use `SimpleDateFormat` (as this is designed to work with `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

*If you can't (or don't want to) migrate from Joda-Time to the new API, you can ignore this section.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

You don't need to create an interval and get the start and end from it. You can create the dates directly:

```
// use system default timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime start = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1499628963860L).atZone(zone);
ZonedDateTime end = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1511809983860L).atZone(zone);

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd/MM HH:mm", new Locale("da", "DK"));
System.out.println(start.format(fmt));
System.out.println(end.format(fmt));
```

The output is:

> sø 09/07 16:36
>   ma 27/11 17:13

If you want to convert to another timezone (instead of JVM default), you can use `ZoneId.of("zonename")`, or `ZoneOffset.UTC` to use UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = dateFormat1;
DateFormatSymbols dfs = dateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols();
dfs.setLocalPatternChars("GyMdkHmsSEDFwWahKzZ");
dateFormat.setDateFormatSymbols(dfs);
Interval interval = new Interval(1499628963860L, 1511809983860L);
DateTime start = new DateTime(interval.getStart());
DateTime end = new DateTime(interval.getEnd());

System.out.println(start.toString(dateFormat.toLocalizedPattern()));
```

this is another way of fix the problem

its the char set to interpret date and time

```
ex :-  y = year 
d = day
M = month 
m = minutes etc
```

in DK t is used inested of Y and u is used insted of d
but Joda time doesnt support t and u